# How do I find my Facebook group ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

My Facebook Group Url is: http://www.facebook.com/groups/284064464943140/
I've read that the group ID is in the Url labelled "id=" or "groupid=" but assume this has changed since there is no such tag in my Url.
I would like to use the group id to insert a group feed into our group website.
Thank you

Answer (score 38):

For finding any facebook group_id or page_id or user_id 
go to inspect element of page and find these in meta tags.

**Group Id**

```
 fb://group/Here_is_your_group_id
```

**Profile user_id**

```
 fb://profile/here_is_your_user_id
```

**Page Id**

```
fb://page/here_is_your_page_id
```

Comment: This should be the answer. No need to rely on other tools.

Comment: yeah that's true. But how can we get the email address of that fb group? @Prashant Srivastav. Such as

Comment: There is no id for my group in the url.

Comment: **groupID** There must be no space between **group** and **ID** when searching in inspect element!

Answer (score 20):

try at http://lookup-id.com/ , get facebook id and group id

Comment: Just checked out, this method is also not working anymore for groups you don't manage.

Comment: Not true. It *works* for groups you don't manage as well. It might not sure work hidden ones though; not sure.

Answer (score 15):

Try http://wallflux.com/facebook_id/, it will guide you through it,

Comment: wallflux gave me a different ID for my page than lookup-id did, and the ID wallflux gave me did not work.

Answer (score 10):

If you need the id for more group for **which you are admin**, a faster method will be to use facebook's [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) tool. You need to get access token for <strike>'user_groups'</strike> **'user_managed_groups'** and make a request by adding groups field:

```
me?fields=groups
```

click submit. This will print all of the groups you are member of and corresponding IDs.

Update: Sorry folks, it seems that Facebook is pulling out the API for groups you don't manage. This whole topic might be obsolete.

Comment: The user_groups permission has been removed, so this doesn't work anymore

Comment: @rasen58 I just checked it. It's still works, but you're partially correct: user_groups is now user_managed_groups

Comment: when I tried it, it only printed out the one group that I'm an admin of. And clicking on the next field gave me a blank response

Comment: That's correct. Since Facebook pull out the API, most of those methods won't work anymore. I though he meant 'my' Facebook group as he is the admin of. Sorry folks

Answer (score 1):

You can look for post_form_id in the source code on Facebook but that is not always accurate.

For groups that do not have the ID in the Facebook URL you can get the page or the group ID using this free simple online tool:
[**http://whatismyfacebookid.com**](http://whatismyfacebookid.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://commentpicker.com/find-facebook-id.php to find a Group ID by entering the FB Group URL. Most of the other online tools don't work anymore.

You can also find it in the source code like mentioned in the other comments. Go to the group page, right click and choose "View Source code" and search for `fb://group/`. The Group ID will be displayed after the slash or after `?id=`

Answer (score 0):

Based upon graph api, you can get group ids as follows:

```
 $facebook->api( '/'.$userId.'/groups', 'GET', array( 'access_token=' => $userToken ));
```

by iterating through its results.

Comment: This doesn't work with version 2.5 because /groups only shows groups where you are admin at.

Answer (score -1):

1) Go to Facebook (www.facebook.com)

2) Click on the little triangle on the top right

3) Select "Manage Groups"

4) Ensure you are on the "Groups" not "Discover" tab (check top left for that)

5) Click on your group

6) Look at your URL from your web browser, it will display something like http://www.facebook.com/groups/12345/about

12345 would be your group in this case.

I hope this helps

Regards

Heider