# Facebook - How to get Page ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I need get the Page ID of my page in Facebook, but I'm having troubles when I try to do this.

My page on Facebook is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/techsempre
```

I'm trying to get the Page ID with Graph, as suggested by a lot of articles in Internet, but I'm getting error. I go to this URL:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/techsempre
```

But, instead a JSON I get the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Someone knows a good way to do that or a solution for this error?

Comment: the page you mentioned does not seem to exist, double check the url.

Comment: The solution for your error is to create the Page.

Comment: I already created the page, it's currently works. Check the website: http://www.techsempre.com/, I have more than 1.8k likes in this page. Try this link: https://www.facebook.com/techsempre?ref=ts&fref=ts

Comment: Oh man, I go to "Manage Permissions" of my facebook page and I found the problem: "Only show this page to viewers in these countries: Brazil". Sorry guys, now's working!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find my Facebook group ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957340/how-do-i-find-my-facebook-group-id)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem!

I go to "Manage Permissions" of my facebook page and I found the problem. In the field "Only show this page to viewers in these countries" someone of my editors wrote "Brazil", so my FanPage was only available for Brazilian - which did not include the Graph.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Accept your answer so that people in future might get benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Developers` site for Facebook.

[Facebook Developers Page](https://developers.facebook.com)

That page has a menu of tools, including the Graph API explorer:

[Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

[image: Graph API Explorer]

There is an option for `Search for a field`

Click `Search for a field` and choose `accounts`.  Then click the `Submit` button.

Interestingly, this will NOT give you the ID to a Facebook ***Group***!!  The ID for a Facebook group seems to simply be in the URL when you visit that group, ***UNLESS*** you have edited the group settings, and `Set Up Group Address`.  In that case, the ID number in the URL won't show up anymore.  So then what do you do to find the ID for the group?  Once you designate a `Group Address`, there is no going back, you can't remove the `Group Address`.