# How to find my own facebook ID? (not the app-scoped ID)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used to be able to go to my Facebook profile page https://www.facebook.com/{Username} and replace the "www" for "graph" https://graph.facebook.com/{Username}.

The answer to that used to be my real facebook ID and some other info, but now I get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username ({Username})",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

Yesterday I made the exact same thing and it worked, but today it doesn't. Is there any other way of finding my ID? Does it work for anyone?

Comment: Maybe you will have to pass your credentials into the api. (the json error talk about oauth)

Comment: What do you _need_ your global user id for anyhow? Every third party app that you use under API v2 will get an app-scoped user id anyway.

Comment: Giving my global ID I can be assigned a Role on all the company's apps, even if I have never logged in any of them. We don't know another way to do it besides going manually to every app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find my Facebook group ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957340/how-do-i-find-my-facebook-group-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

graph.facebook.com/{Username} is not available now but [lookup-id.com](https://lookup-id.com) still can find your facebook ID

Answer (score 4):

For finding any facebook group_id or page_id or user_id go to inspect element of page and find these in meta tags.

**Group Id**

```
 fb://group/Here_is_your_group_id
```

**Profile user_id**

```
 fb://profile/here_is_your_user_id
```

**Page Id**

```
fb://page/here_is_your_page_id
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already 3 exact same questions in the last 2 hours. Please use the search function of StackOverflow before posting a question!

You cannot get the `username` field anymore. This is very well documented in the Facebook docs.

See

- [graph.facebook.com/username does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868201/graph-facebook-com-username-does-not-work)

Comment: Yes, I've read them. I know the usual call with the username does not work.
My question is: now that this doesn't work, how can I find my own fb ID?

Comment: The user id is now always app-scoped. There is no global id. It's all in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have your user ID, the simplest way would be to use an online service (like this one: http://getuserid.com) and paste your Facebook username.

If you need the user ID by programming, this is different. You could in this case parse the HTML code of the page (CTRL + U will show you the HTML code of the page) and search for the term **entity_id**, which is the user ID. You could then use regex to extract the information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get your Facebook ID via the Graph API!

You can use a regular expression to find your Facebook ID. If you paste the source of a profile page (or page/group) inside http://regexr.com/3gi7q it will match the Facebook ID for you.

It is using the following regex to find the Facebook ID:

`/fb:\/\/profile\/(\d+)|fb:\/\/page\/\?id=(\d+)|fb:\/\/group\/\?id=(\d+)/;`

You can also use the tool i created and just fill in your profile url: https://commentpicker.com/find-facebook-id.php

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Facebook profile and right click on your cover photo, if you copy the URL it should have your Facebook id in it like so. `fbid` is what you want. I don't there's any AIP for it anymore. Looks like Facebook may be finally phasing it out.

`https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1512641059003115&set=a.1376251679308721.1073741827.100007717054203&type=1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sources already identified or you can right click below the navigation bar and view page source.  Use your CTRL+F (find) and search for [profile_owner&quot].

The number listed shortly thereafter will be your global ID.  It will generally look like this:

> [profile_owner":"10000320024513431&quot].

The # is listed multiple times (like 75) in the data and follows terms such as `["profile_id"]`, `["uid":]`, and `[?profileid=]` to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

I always us this tool https://www.graphsearcher.com/ to find my personal facebook ID. Hope can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Head over to [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname) and authenticate with it, you can then use the Graph explorer to get your ID. You'll also need an access token to view the https://graph.facebook.com/{ID} page.

Comment: This will return an app-scoped user id.

Answer (score -3):

I just tested this for you and it works correct.
I can see FB source and above i can see my FB ID also.
I used https://graph.facebook.com/username and tested with firefox.
Maybe your using it wrong per accident?
It seems like code 803 means no valid username.
Are you really sure you are using a correct username?

You can also try below link to find your FB ID.

http://findmyfacebookid.com/

Good  luck mate!

Comment: I'm sure it's the right username. I've asked some friends and coworkers to try the same but the result is the same.
http://findmyfacebookid.com/ used to work, but now throws error: "Unable to lookup Facebook numeric ID. Please try again..."

Comment: I've tested it with both chrome and firefox too.